# Boost Client-Server Connection Stability

Tags: c++, boost, tcp

I am quite new in setting Client-Server connections and I have a problem about sending data between two computers. My code is working well by "localhost" but with two computers over network, it crashes somewhere. In localhost, I can  transfer 22 MB data, my largest data file.

For two computers connection:
I have a small example to transfer data and the data amount of it is around 11 kb. This example is also working well here. However, next bigger example with size 0f 230 kb crashes.

I am using synchronous TCP.

SERVER:

```
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor( io_service, tcp::endpoint( tcp::v4( ), 40986 ) );
    CDBReader* sender = CDBReader::getInstance( );
    for ( ;; )
    {
       tcp::socket socket( io_service );
       mySocket = &socket;
       acceptor.accept( *mySocket );
  }
```

CLIENT:

```
try
{
 boost::asio::io_service io_service;
 tcp::resolver resolver( io_service );
 tcp::resolver::query query( serverName, "40986" );
 tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve( query );
 tcp::socket socket( io_service );
 mySocket = &socket;
 boost::asio::connect( *mySocket, endpoint_iterator );
 boost::system::error_code error;
}
```

This is how I create the connection.

And this is the fuction that I used in Server to send data. Acc to the amount of data, I am sending after dividing into parts.

```
void vtkCDBConnectorSource::sendString( std::string message )
{
  std::cout << "I am in sendString" << std::endl;
  int loopCounter = message.size() / charArraySize + 1;
  size_t mSize = message.size();

  std::stringstream SStream;
  SStream << loopCounter;
  std::string noLoop = SStream.str( );
  //  std::cout << "loopCounter = " << loopCounter << std::endl;
 if(loopCounter >= 10 && loopCounter < 100)
 {
   std::stringstream digitNumberSizeStream;
   digitNumberSizeStream << 2;
   std::string digitNumberSize = digitNumberSizeStream.str( );
   digitNumberSizeStream.str(std::string());
   digitNumberSizeStream.clear();
   //   std::cout << "digitNumberSize = " << digitNumberSize << std::endl;
   //   std::cout << "noLoop = " << noLoop << std::endl;

   size_t s10 = mySocket->send( boost::asio::buffer( digitNumberSize ) );
   size_t s11 = mySocket->send( boost::asio::buffer( noLoop ) );
 }
 else if( loopCounter >= 100 && loopCounter < 1000)
 {
   std::stringstream digitNumberSizeStream;
   digitNumberSizeStream << 3;
   std::string digitNumberSize = digitNumberSizeStream.str( );
   digitNumberSizeStream.str(std::string());
   digitNumberSizeStream.clear();
   //    std::cout << "digitNumberSize = " << digitNumberSize << std::endl;
   //    std::cout << "noLoop = " << noLoop << std::endl;

  size_t s10 = mySocket->send( boost::asio::buffer( digitNumberSize ) );
  size_t s11 = mySocket->send( boost::asio::buffer( noLoop ) );
 }
 else if( loopCounter >= 1000)
 {
   std::stringstream digitNumberSizeStream;
   digitNumberSizeStream << 4;
   std::string digitNumberSize = digitNumberSizeStream.str( );
   digitNumberSizeStream.str(std::string());
   digitNumberSizeStream.clear();
  //    std::cout << "digitNumberSize = " << digitNumberSize << std::endl;
  //    std::cout << "noLoop = " << noLoop << std::endl;

 size_t s10 = mySocket->send( boost::asio::buffer( digitNumberSize ) );
 size_t s11 = mySocket->send( boost::asio::buffer( noLoop ) );
}
else
{
   std::stringstream digitNumberSizeStream;
   digitNumberSizeStream << 1;
   std::string digitNumberSize = digitNumberSizeStream.str( );
   digitNumberSizeStream.str(std::string());
   digitNumberSizeStream.clear();

   //   std::cout << "digitNumberSize = " << digitNumberSize << std::endl;
   //   std::cout << "noLoop = " << noLoop << std::endl;

   size_t s10 = mySocket->send( boost::asio::buffer( digitNumberSize ) );
   size_t s11 = mySocket->send( boost::asio::buffer( noLoop ) );
  }
 SStream.str( std::string( ) );
 SStream.clear( );

  int i = 0;
  while( i < loopCounter )
  {
     int secLoop = 0;
     if( mSize >= charArraySize)
  {
      secLoop = charArraySize;
      mSize = mSize - secLoop;
   }
   else
   {
     secLoop = mSize;
   }

   std::string tempMessage;
   for( size_t j=0; j<secLoop; j++)
   {
     tempMessage.push_back( message[charArraySize*i + j] );
   }

   std::stringstream messageSizeStream;
   messageSizeStream << secLoop;

   std::string messageSize = messageSizeStream.str( );
   size_t dataDigitSize = messageSizeStream.str().size();
   std::stringstream messageDigitStream;
   messageDigitStream << dataDigitSize;

   std::string messageDigit = messageDigitStream.str( );

   // std::cout << "messageDigit = " << messageDigit << std::endl;
   //    std::cout << "messageSize = " << messageSize << std::endl;

  size_t s12 = mySocket->send( boost::asio::buffer( messageDigit ) );
  size_t s13 = mySocket->send( boost::asio::buffer( messageSize ) );
  size_t s14 = mySocket->send( boost::asio::buffer( tempMessage ) );
  messageSizeStream.str( std::string( ) );
  messageSizeStream.clear( );
  ++i;
}

//  std::cout<<"SendString Finished"<<std::endl;
mySendStream.str( std::string( ) );
mySendStream.clear( );
}
```

And this is the function in client side to receive the data:

```
size_t vtkCDBConnectorSource::DataContainer( )
{
   std::cout << "I am in DataContainer" << std::endl;
   char* sizeOfLoop = new char[10];
   char* noOfLoops= new char[100];

   size_t dataLength;
   size_t loopsizeDigit = mySocket->receive( boost::asio::buffer( sizeOfLoop, 1 ) );
   std::stringstream lStream;
   lStream << sizeOfLoop;
   size_t numberOfloops;
   lStream >> numberOfloops ;
   lStream.str(std::string());
   lStream.clear();
   std::cout<<"Number of Digits for Loops= "<<numberOfloops<<std::endl;
  size_t sizeDigit = mySocket->receive( boost::asio::buffer(noOfLoops,     numberOfloops   ) );

   std::stringstream RStream;
   RStream << noOfLoops;

   size_t loopSize;
   RStream >> loopSize ;
   RStream.str(std::string());
   RStream.clear();
   std::cout << "loopSize = " << loopSize << std::endl;

   int i = 0;
   while( i < loopSize )
   {
    char* dataDigit= new char[100];
    size_t sizeDataDigit = mySocket->receive( boost::asio::buffer( dataDigit, 1 ) );

    RStream << dataDigit;
    size_t digitNumber;
    RStream >> digitNumber;
    RStream.str(std::string());
    RStream.clear();
    char* dataSize = new char[100];
   //    std::cout << "digitNumber = " << digitNumber << std::endl;
   size_t sizeData = mySocket->receive( boost::asio::buffer( dataSize, digitNumber ) );

   RStream << dataSize;
   size_t dataAmount;
   RStream >> dataAmount;
   RStream.str(std::string());
   RStream.clear( );

   char* data= new char[100000];
   //    std::cout << "dataAmount = " << dataAmount << std::endl;

   dataLength = mySocket->receive( boost::asio::buffer( data, dataAmount ) );

   std::cout << "dataLength = " << dataLength << std::endl;

   int k = 0;

   while ( dataLength-- > 0 ) // maybe need to divide by 2
   {
     myReceivedStream << data[k++];
   }

   delete[] data;
   delete[] dataDigit;
   delete[] dataSize;
   ++i;
   }
   delete[] sizeOfLoop;
   delete[] noOfLoops;
    std::cout << " ---- Data Container FINISHED--- " << std::endl;
    return dataLength;
 }
```

I hope I can tell my problem, if there is any point which is unclear, please tell me know. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I am unwilling to go through this mountain of code, so a tip: as you receive chunks of code - print out how large was this chunk, and how much you've received so far. Do the same on client side and compare notes.

Comment: I did that but it does not help. Actually, I can summarize the code, for example the size of my data sent is 5000 then I am telling the number of digts to the client, in this case it is four. Another thing in the code, if data is large, it is divided into small amounts like samples haivng size of 1000. The reason why I shared the big part of the code to understand is there any bad usage of boost communication classes creating this unstability.

Comment: Well, my point with taking note wasn't exactly random. The difference between localhost and remote is that when your data leaves outside of your pc, it will get fragmented. While in local it went swiftly in just one packet, over the internet it will be fragmented. And if it is crashes over the net, but not locally, then your most likely issue is that dreaded fragmentation.

Comment: In the smallest example, I dont do fragmentation and it works. After your answer, I tried to send next bigger example without fragmentation but it does not solve the problem. Any other suggestion  or detection,@Puciek?

Comment: What do you mean without fragmentation? This is what your network does for you - takes your data and breaks it down into small packets and then sends them through, you can't control that. This creates quite a few issues, because you may even wind up in odd spots where your socket may consider that it's EOF, even though it's not.

And if the issue exists only when actual network is involved, but never in local test, you are not handling issues arising from it right. And if you don't see that in logs, you need to log way more details.

Answer (score 1):

This code is undefined behavior:

```
tcp::socket socket( io_service );
mySocket = &socket;
```

You're creating a `tcp::socket` in the scope of your `try` block, then storing the address of it in `mySocket`, which exists outside of this scope. Once you leave your `try` block, the `tcp::socket` is destroyed and `mySocket` is still pointing to the destroyed object.

It may work for a while, until some other code runs and overwrites the portion of the stack that your destroyed `tcp::socket` object was occupying.

Once you fix this, the same problem applies to your `io_service`; you construct the socket with a reference to it, then allow it to be destroyed, so the fixed `tcp::socket` object is still holding a reference to the destroyed `io_service`.